# How to split a file based on a matching condition of a column?

Tags: bash, awk

I know that by using:

```
awk '($18 ~ 0)' file > match
```

I get all the lines that have a 0 on 18th field. Thus I tried to implement the same logic to split a file based on wether its 18th field has an "0" or not:

```
awk -F, '{ if ($18 ~ 0) print > "match"; else print > "not_match"}' file
```

But is not working, no line is printed on "match".

What am I doing wrong? Do you know other way to do this in bash?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Does it work if you print on the console instead of redirecting it to files?

Comment: works for me lines are in files `match` and `not_match`

Comment: can you provide one line data that you thought should sit in "match" but not?

Comment: What if you quote your field separator? `awk -F "," '{ if ($18 ~ 0) print > "match"; else print > "not_match"}' file` in bash comma as a specific meaning, maybe bash doesn't understand it's an option in the awk call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal complete example of splitting the lines of a file conditionally based on field values:

```
[me@host]$ cat > /tmp/blah
0 Yes
1 No
1 No
0 Yes
1 No
[me@host]$ awk '($1 ~ 0) { print > "/tmp/match"; next } { print > "/tmp/non_match" }' /tmp/blah
[me@host]$ cat /tmp/match
0 Yes
0 Yes
[me@host]$ cat /tmp/non_match
1 No
1 No
1 No
```

Comment: how does this answer OP's question : `What am I doing wrong?`

Comment: @Kent: This answers the OP's headline question `How to split a file based on a matching condition of a column?`

Comment: true. but IMO, your solution has no difference from what OP has tried. right?

Comment: I've provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the OP has become confused with their code / example, this may provide some clarity. This method is easier to adapt to multiple conditions going to multiple files.

Comment: Okay, all answers are trying to help people here. I see that, that's why I don't downvote any answer, unless it was totally wrong one. And you took time to create example and prove that your solution works on the example. it's great. However I still feel this screenshot -like answer is like "cannot reproduce your problem" or "it is working here" comments. If OP's solution didn't work, I cannot imagine your one-liner would work for him. There must be some problem that is hiding behind, and we don't know yet. and anyway, it's my personal feeling.

Comment: This is worse than OP's attempt as it is less extensible, and also doesn't attempt to actually answer OP's question. Also you can't fit details into the headline question so taking it literally is silly, it is more of an overview of what the question will be about.

Comment: @User112638726: I respectfully disagree. The title of a question is the crux of what is trying to be achieved. It specifies the input used and the observed output. It is more extensible because another clause can be added at the start to redirect a different line elsewhere.

Comment: @Kent if my "one-liner" still doesn't work for the OP, then he's got different problems. I'm not idly saying *works fine for me* without specifying the input used. I wrote this to help with an idea of how it could help.

Comment: @MattH Thanks! You provide exactly the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: @Geparada: You are very welcome; I'm glad I was able to help you

Comment: @MattH I still disagree but edit your answer and I'll remove my downvote as apparently this has worked for OP.

Comment: @User112638726: exactly what do you think is lacking from my answer? Chatty pre-amble? Did you notice the OP also asks *Do you know other way to do this in bash?*

Comment: @MattH `What am I doing wrong?` It doesn't answer this, as OP's original code should work fine, and I can see no reason why this answer would work and theirs wouldn't. This is effectively the same as OP's attempt and in my opinion a worse way to do it. But it is irrelevant anyway as it OP is happy with it. When i said edit your answer, i meant literally do anything to it(add a . then remove it again), so i can remove the downvote.

Comment: @User112638726: I still don't know what was going wrong for the OP; I don't actually need to know. I've provided a working example and it has helped the OP. You're trying to blackmail me with a downvote to edit my answer to include something neither of us know?

Comment: @MattH No I'm saying I did downvote, but  as this answer has worked for OP i want to remove it, but i am unable to unless you edit your answer. I was suggesting you make an arbitrary edit to your answer so that i could remove the downvote.

Comment: @User112638726: Hah, that I didn't realise. I took *but edit your answer and I'll remove my downvote* that you were planning to hold me hostage to a change in content.